# How to choose the next CSS3/HTML5/JS/GRID framework for Rails 3.1.3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, frameworks, css

I'm on the way to choose the next CSS3/HTML5/JS/GRID on the edge framework.

Very heavy task, there are tons. Moreover, I'd like having smooth integration with Rails 3.1.3 platform ( which means asset pipeling and so on ... ).

Do you have something to suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://html5boilerplate.com/

EDIT: [A Guide to HTML5 Boilerplate for Rails Developers](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-html5-boilerplate.html)

Comment: thanks, a very good source ;-)